# Error on installing apps in office 365 : AADSTS650051: Application 'CLIENT_ID' is requesting permissions that are either invalid or out of date

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365-apps

I have a few multi-tenant application on AAD App which requests access to Mail, Calendar, Contacts and Tasks . The apps works successfully for a few years without any issue, but last few days started to get error :

`"AADSTS650051: Application 'CLIENT_ID' is requesting permissions that are either invalid or out of date"`

All of them !!! Without anything that changed in apps permissions settings. So, new domains can't now install those apps.

Remove app from the installed domain and install it again, doesn't helps.

Please advise. 
Thanks

Comment: What permissions/scopes exactly are you requiring on those apps?

Comment: Well, many. We are backups for 365 and SharePoint, so ews, mail, contacts, tasks, notes, sharepoint, graph api and so. Ut we found some strange permissions that looks suspicious. Called Deprecated_ThreatIntelligence.Read and not possible to remove it, saying removed, but still appears. I think there's a bug in Azure, those permissions are not allows to install the app and they can't be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found an issue - two permissions, one of them is `Deprecated_ThreatIntelligence.Read`, was not able to remove it, when tried to remove got ok, but permission was there again. After talking with MS support (paid support, after 48 hours of phone and email conversations) got nothing from them expect :

> I would like to inform you that I have reached out to my peer
>   engineers with all this information and waiting for their suggestion
>   to proceed with further investigation on it.
>
> I would request you to allow me sometime so that I can discuss with my
>   peer engineers and get back to you with an update on it.

Had no choice and needed to solve this quick as possible, found a way to remove , downloaded manifest (it'a app configuration JSON),  removed problematic permission (not an easy task, as there's only guids) and uploaded manifest again. Issue solved. 
Shame on microsoft support !!!! One of the useless paid support I ever saw. Can't do anything except waiting for feedback from engineers. This issue supposed to be fixed by support within 5-10 minutes, once they have request id and correlation id, but they didn't find a solution up till now. And shame on Microsoft, lost customers for last 10 days, due to their weird bugs.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is exactly as described in the error message. Credentials for your app has expired.

Go to Azure AD -> App registration -> Your app -> Create new key

Comment: Well, Not related to keys and credentials. Error saying "is requesting permissions that are either invalid or out of date". Permissions are outdated, not keys. And creating new key doesn't solved. Btw, if key was expired I won't be able to install app.

Comment: Did you try remove and re-adding permissions after new key was generate?

Comment: Yes, There's some permissions that somehow can't be removed, called Deprecated_ThreatIntelligence.Read. Again error is not talking about expired keys, error talking about expired permissions. Now somehow those permissions became not removable, so I do think Azure have a bug, that started a week ago or so and more questions and bug reports will come.

Comment: Hmm, sounds wierd. Yes, I thought it was the same error I had the other day so I was mistaken about the key.

Comment: Talked with someone in MS which said it should be deleted from permissions on the specific app so probably a bug then.

Comment: Well, found a way to remove , download manifest removed problematic permission (not an easy task, as there's only guids) and uploaded manifest again. Issue solved. Shame on microsoft. Lost customers for last 10 days, due to their weird bugs.

Answer (score -1):

This deprecation warning has been in the documentation for a while. The removal of the scope just happened within last couple months.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis#specify-the-permissions-your-app-requires-to-access-the-office-365-management-apis

Paragraph 3.

Comment: Thanks, the issue that it was unable to remove those permissions, no error, just each time they returned back. This is the issue.